# Qt-Creator won't compile - No such file or directory "c++config.h"

Tags: android, c++, qt, compiler-errors

I've been trying to create a simple "Hello World" Application for Android with the Qt-Creator.
When Building, I get an error that says:

```
bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory

#include <bits/c++config.h>

(D:\android-ndk-rb16\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\utility)
```

I have not found a working solution online yet. I don't know what to do since this Include is happening in a file I've never modified (utility).
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Ensure that the Kit is configured correctly and in particular, it is using the correct compiler.

Comment: Qt supports android ndk 10e, the version you have is very current and is not supported, for more information read the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html

Comment: Thank you! Changing the ndk to version 10 e fixed it.